# How to add SSL for home server?

Tags: apache, ssl, https, cloudflare

I have a home server, which is behind the Cloudflare, also it works via HTTPS, because of certificates, given by Cloudflare. But my web page has an audio player:

```
<audio >
  <source src="http://192.168.0.100:8000/audio" >
</audio>
```

And this makes the page insecure for browsers. Audiostream generates by Liquidsoap, which has the ability to encrypt streams, but SSL certs given by Cloudflare can't be accepted by the browser.

How can I fix this problem and make my site safe for browsers?

Comment: You need to do at least three things: (a) you have to use a domain or subdomain for serving this content, and (b) it cannot be a LAN address, it has to be an internet address. You can proxy from one address to another if it helps. Also (c) it has to be HTTPS in order to not trigger a "mixed content" warning.

Comment: If the audio stream is on a home server, then you will need a static IP, or a dynamic IP that is updated in your (sub) domain DNS. The static IP is easiest. Usually consumer ISPs don't offer static IP addresses, but you can sometimes have them as an optional extra.

Comment: thanx for comment. A&B not sure because it actually works and plays sound, for example Opera just makes a warning about "mixing content" but still works. c) Exactly, and the question is how. I tried to make "Forwarding URL" with Cloudflare https://example.com/audio => http://192.168.0.100/audio but it won't help and Chrom still can notice spoofing.

Comment: Remember that 192.168.* is reserved for local (LAN) addresses. So Cloudflare machines would recognise it, if it exists at all, as being on the Cloudflare LAN. Here you would put the static IP of your home server.

Comment: I have static IP but I don't want to make it visible so I use Cloudflare to hide it.

Comment: I assume that Cloudflare would proxy content from a Cloudflare server to your home server, such that the connection from the user to Cloudflare is encrypted, and the connection from Cloudflare to your house is unencrypted. That would work, but the claim you are making to your users is misleading, since it is not end-to-end encrypted.

Comment: "I have static IP but I don't want to make it visible so I use Cloudflare to hide it." - OK, so can your audio stream DNS point to a CloudFlare IP address, and then CloudFlare does proxying in the background?

Comment: NO 192.168 works fine, because my domain uses CF's NS servers and in CF i make A-record which points to my static IP, so all LAN adress forwards to my local network.

Comment: Your HTML as it stands should not work, I can't see how it can. It will work for you, since you are on that LAN, but I cannot understand how at 192.168.* address would forward out to the internet only to come back to your static IP. Perhaps someone else can see what is going on here.

Comment: OMG You're right! It wokrs only in LAN and not via mobile network...

Comment: Right, that makes sense. So you need to see if CloudFlare have a proxy feature that allows you to put their static IP address into your DNS, and all traffic is forwarded in hops from the user to CloudFlare to you. Your internet-facing IP address will be needed for the last hop. If CloudFlare does not have this feature, you could set up your own proxy using a plain VPS.

Comment: This is little complicated for me. I have router with Iptables, so maybe I can use link like src="https://example.com:8000/audio". Then I can listen port 8000 on my router and forward it to 192.168.0.100:8000?

Comment: Indeed you can. However I was mindful of your earlier constraint, which was "I have static IP but I don't want to make it visible so I use Cloudflare to hide it". If you don't mind adding your static IP into your domain/subdomain DNS then it's easier to do what you want.

Comment: As a result: my link is src="http://example.com/audio", and I use my local webserver to proxy */audio => localhost:8000/audio. This works fine, but I had to give up ssl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved with the help of local proxy. Link on webpage is:

```
<source src="https://example.com/audio" >
```

Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName example.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/
SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile ssl/example.com.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile ssl/example.com.key
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

ProxyPass /audio http://localhost:8000/audio
ProxyPassReverse /audio http://localhost:8000/audio

</VirtualHost>
```